# Java method returning null pointer?

Tags: java

So I have a method that is checked when a user runs a command, well I get getting this wretched error that it's returning a NullPointer...

Heres my method,

```
   public boolean openReferal(String name) {
    for(String s : m.refferalSessions) {
        if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And heres how i'm implementing it...

```
   if(check.openReferal(sender.getName() + ":" + args[0])) {
            sender.sendMessage(openReferal);
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NullPointerException` means that you are dereferencing a null variable somewhere. The stack trace will tell you exactly which line is causing the problem, and from that you can deduce which variable is set to null.

From your code, there are only a few suspects: `m`, `m.referralSessions`, `check` and `sender`. Check that they are all initialized properly, and use the information in the exception to help track down the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help you gave me a new insight on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Methods do not, in practice, return NullPointerExceptions; rather, they throw them. However, methods can return `null`.

However, boolean methods *cannot* return null, as primitives cannot be null.  The NullPointerException here could be the result of `sender`  or `check` being null when you invoke their corresponding methods on them.

Comment: He means it's *throwing* an Exception. Also, methods *can* return Exceptions.

Comment: @Bohemian My answer does not state anywhere that methods cannot return Exceptions, and the second paragraph directly addresses the NullPointerException being thrown. Regardless, I've clarified in the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

`s` could possibly be null.

Can you do a debug to see the value of `s`.

Comment: I am now, will post when i have.